# Parse push notifications not being saved in database after migration to windows server 2008

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, windows-server-2008

I am using Windows Server 2008 for MongoDb and Parse migration. My Android/iOS app uses Parse push, which is triggered when the user posts a comment. Everything was working fine (MongoDb was being updated correctly and I was receiving the notifications) until I made changes to Android manifest and switched to GCM. Now the pushes are not showing up in either of the two databases (Parse and MongoDB) and neither am I receiving the pushes.

I followed parse-server-example on Github and parse push migration guidelines to the book. Can anyone please point out what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: did you setup the pushes in Parse server config file?

Comment: You mean app.json? Can you please provide me with details. I have no experience of working on servers.

Comment: Everything is on the github [https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Push](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Push)

Comment: I have followed this tutorial to the book but my notifications are not being saved in the database(mongodb), even though the push status says "push ok"

Comment: Push notifications are not stored in some class... It sends them directly to the device